# Django, db update, south and sqliteman: a confirmation. Not really a question. Is it better?

Tags: database, django, django-south

I have seen that actually, after asking in stackoverflow.com, there might be a lot of equivalent questions.. But I got the box where to write already and my google searches
are not any better. (I was testing blekko.com for a while.. as a search engine.. give it a try)

Back to the question:

If I have: models.py

```
class someclass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And I run all the stuff till the site is working...

Now I do (models.py):

```
class someclass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And I use sqliteman or phpmyadmin to add a column named 'sub_title' which will get some
default value, namely NULL. (regardless of some django constrains, like not NULL)

Would I brake something within django?

I guess I would always have the possibility to dump the db and read it back.
Not sure yet how to do it in django in a clean way but there should be a way.
Is there such a way?

My question stops here.

But as additional hint, I did check south which didn't work for me 'right out of the box',
in particular for an existing project. Before to get into some other problems,
I realized that I only need columns updates while developing the site.

I present to my customer (this is at present a free/free no money situation)
the stages of development... and I do not want to reset the DB at every version.

Comment: I'm guessing this would break Django unless you updated the models to reflect this.

Comment: You could try using South (http://south.aeracode.org/) which solves exactly this problem. However, I do wonder why this question has a "south" tag on it.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler if the column was nullable and null by default it woudn't break django, you wouldn't be able to use the column at all from django, but it won't break anything. Well I guess it depends on what you mean by break. It won't stop it from working and cause a server error if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Rafe, of course the model will be hand made updated. @Martin this was on the top. Why using south? Actually the question was another: I couldn't get south on an existing project. Technically I can reproduce the project. Which one would be the advantage of south?

Comment: Indeed the DB has nothing to do with django (of course) so being permissive on the DB side cannot break any django feature. I guess that the point is if it is really simple that a class variable can be right away declared and used independently from the DB...